# How to display login error message on the login page with php

Tags: php

When login is successful, the user is redirected to the main page of my site. My code redirects the user to a blank page when they input incorrect login details (login_parse.php), and here the error message 'Login unsuccessful' appears. I want the error message to appear on the login page (index.php).

Login page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<head>
</head>

<body>


<form id='registration_form' action='registration.php' method='post'>
    <input id ='new_username' type='text' name='new_username'     placeholder='Create a username' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please create   a username')"required></input>
    <input id ='new_password' type='password' name='new_password'     placeholder='Create a password' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please create     a password')" required></input>
    <input id ='new_email' type='email' name='new_email' placeholder='Enter   a   valid student.lboro.ac.uk email     address'oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid     student.lboro.ac.uk email address')" required></input>
    <input id ='register_button' type='submit' value='Sign Up'/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

login_parse.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

include "dbconnect.php";

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username= '".$username."' AND   password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
  $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error);

       if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
          $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
          header("Location: shownewposts.php");
          exit();


          } 
          else {

            echo "Login unsuccessful";
            exit();
          }

}

?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page use JavaScript and AJAX - unless you want to reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension for input filter and PDO.

You can create a session variable in else statement.
Something Like:

```php
   <?php

   session_start();

   include "connect.php";

   if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
     unset( $_SESSION['errorMessage'] );
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username= '".$username."' AND   password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
     $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
         $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
         $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
         header("Location: shownewposts.php");
         exit();
     } 
     else {
         $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = true;
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit();
     }

   }

   ?>
```

And in index.php check if session variabile exists and print message

```php
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>     
    
    <?php
       if (isset($_SESSION['errorMessage'])){
         echo "<span style='color:red;'>Check your input</span>";
       }
    ?>
    <form id='registration_form' action='registration.php' method='post'>
        <input id ='new_username' type='text' name='new_username'     placeholder='Create a username' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please create   a username')"required></input>
        <input id ='new_password' type='password' name='new_password'     placeholder='Create a password' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please create     a password')" required></input>
        <input id ='new_email' type='email' name='new_email' placeholder='Enter   a   valid student.lboro.ac.uk email     address'oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid     student.lboro.ac.uk email address')" required></input>
        <input id ='register_button' type='submit' value='Sign Up'/>
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```